# Javascript: How can I declare non-global static methods?

Tags: javascript

How can I declare non-global static methods in js?

```
foo.bar = function() {
  function testing{
    console.log("statckoverlow rocks!");
  }
  function testing2{
    console.log("testing2 funtction");
  }
}
```

How can I call the testing functions? I am a newbie in JS.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want an object.

```
foo.bar = {
  testing: function() {
    console.log("statckoverlow rocks!");
  },
  testing2: function() {
    console.log("testing2 funtction");
  }
};
```

Then, call `foo.bar.testing()`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
foo.bar = (function() {
  var testing = function () {
    console.log("statckoverlow rocks!");
  };
  var testing2 = function () {
    console.log("testing2 funtction");
  };
  return {
    testing: testing,
    testing2: testing2
  };
}());

// call them
foo.bar.testing();
foo.bar.testing2();
```

Comment: why do we need for.bar = (function() {.....}());  it seems make things complicated

Comment: **@Kit Ho** It's a self executing function that creates a singleton. If you're using "classes" or prototypes in JavaScript, check my answer I believe that's what you mean by static method.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
var foo = {
    bar: {
        testing: function()
        {
            console.log("statckoverlow rocks!");
        },
        testing2: function()
        {
            console.log("testing2 funtction");
        }
    }
};


foo.bar.testing();
foo.bar.testing2();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Constructor
function Foo() {
  var myvar = 'hey'; // private
  this.property = myvar;
  this.method = function() { ... };
}
Foo.prototype = {
  staticMethod: function() {
    console.log( this.property );
  }
}
var foo = new Foo();
foo.staticMethod(); //=> hey
```